# Trigonometric Identities Need Help

Tags: trigonometry

I'm struggling with this. Can someone help me?

I need to make $$-\sin(x)$$ into $$(\cot(x)-\csc(x))(\cos(x)+1)$$

Does anyone know the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate? http://math.stackexchange.com/q/879158/409

Comment: Well you could go in the reverse way first (i.e try converting $(\cot(x)-\csc(x))(cos(x)+1)$ to $-\sin(x)$). It'll probably help in figuring the algorithm.

Comment: Sometimes it's best if you ignore your teachers advice and not express everything in terms of sines and cosines, which can get quite messy in certain situations. Here, I utilize $\cot x=\frac{\csc x}{\sec x}$ $$-\sin x=-\sin^2 x\csc x=-(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)\csc x=(1+\cos x)(\frac{1}{\sec x}-1)\csc x=(1+\cos x)(\cot x-\csc x)$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin x=\frac{\sin^2 x}{\sin x} $$

$$\frac{\sin^2 x}{\sin x} = \frac{1- \cos^2 x}{sin x} = \frac{(1- \cos x)(1+\cos x)}{sin x} = {(\csc x- \cot x)(1+\cos x)} $$

So

$$-\sin x = {(\cot x - \csc x)(1+\cos x)} $$

Answer (score 2):

$$\cot x-\csc x=\frac{\cos x-1}{\sin x} $$

$$\implies(\cot x-\csc x)(\cos x+1)=-\frac{1-\cos^2x}{\sin x}=\cdots$$